# How can update the object in array by PATCH with REST API if the array is null?

Tags: arrays, rest, api, patch

I get an issue don't know how to update an object in the array by PATCH with REST API in case the array is null.

EX:
 - I have a contact with the model as below:

```
 {
    "id":"",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "addresses": [
     {
      "first_address": "",
      "city": "",
     }    
     ]
}
```

- How can I update the first_address, city with using PATCH if "addresses":null ?

  ```
  {
  "id":"090909",
  "first_name": "Ellen",
  "last_name": "Cao",
  "addresses": null
  ```

  }
- Always get the error:
  **Request by PATCH**

  ```
   [{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/first_name",
    "value": "H"
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/last_name",
    "value": "Update"
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/addresses/0/first_address",
    "value": "Tran Hung Dao"
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/addresses/0/city",
    "value": "HCM"
  }
  ]
  ```

  **Returned error:**
  {
  "message": "For operation 'replace', the target location specified by path '/addresses/0/first_address' was not found (/addresses/0/first_address)."
  }

  - Also get error if using "op" is "add".

    [{
          "op": "add",
          "path": "/addresses/-/first_address",
          "value": "Tran Hung Dao"
        },
        {
          "op": "add",
          "path": "/addresses/-/city",
          "value": "HCM"
        }]

Returned error:
  {
    "message": "For operation 'add', the target location specified by path '/addresses/-/first_address' was not found (/addresses/-/first_address)."
}
Is there any way to add "adresses" by using PATCH ?
Thanks so much if someone can help me.

Comment: You can't update what you don't have.

Comment: Can I use op is "add" to add the address by PATCH ?

Comment: I'd deserialize it into a `List<your_type>` to manage the values.

Comment: Thanks, but you may not understand my question. I just ask if there is any way to replace/add an object in array in case the array is null when using PATCH of REST API

Comment: Then I think this article may help you: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-json-patch-partial-api-updates

Comment: if C# is involved, please add relevant C# code. Or if there is no relevant C# code, then please remove the C# tag.